# Code signing issue in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode5

My project has a sub-project. It's not being code-signed:

[image]

Even though I disabled code-signing, I still get this error:

```
Code Sign error: Multiple matching codesigning identities found: Multiple codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “Mac Developer” were found.
```

When I look in the keychain, there's no duplicate key of "Mac Developer". I didn't have this issue in Xcode 4.x.

How can I fix this?

---

### EDIT

The issue description appears under "LaunchAtLoginHelper", so I'm positive that this project is causing the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## EDIT

This issue was fixed in **Xcode v5.0.1**.
The **General** tab is now available even in sub-projects.

[image]

---

## Solution

---

Apparently you have to open the sub-project separately, because otherwise you will not get the **General** tab in the projects settings.

Even tough there was no code-signing identity, you need to separately disable code-signing in Xcode 5.

[image]

Just choose **None**, open your main project again and it should compile correctly.

Comment: NSAddict - where is that selection? I can't find it under the project or target properties. But I only know to look under Code Signing.

Comment: @noloader Make sure to open the solution that causes the error, and not the workspace. Then this tab should be visible.

Comment: Visible where? I still don't see it.

Comment: @strange I described it above, you need to open the project that is causing the error **separately**. Then the project settings will be available in the **General** tab

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It solved my problem on the "add the in-app purchase entitlement to apple id" warning i get from the "capabilities" tab